# In Goland, how can I hide test files underneath each non-test file?

Tags: goland

In Go, it is "idiomatic" to place test files next to the files containing the code under test.

Regardless of whether or not this is a good software engineering practice, in Goland IDE you can hide tests underneath the code under test as if it were a subdirectory.

Where is this setting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can follow the instructions from [this help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/file-nesting-dialog.html).

A quick reference is to do the following:

- under the project view window
- click on the cogwheel
- select File Nesting...
- click on the "Child file suffix" under ".go" extension
- add "_test.go" to the list and click OK

---

Here's the file nesting option:

[image]

Once chosen, add the following:

[image: file nesting]

Comment: Great, this wasn't found easily at all. Many thanks! (I'm adding a screenshot for future users).